# How can we block ibm mq amqp subscriber from accessing topic of other subscriber?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, amqp, jms-topic

We have two amqp channels running under queue manager QM01:

CHL01 with user abc and running on port 5672
CHL02 with user xyz and running on port 5671

We have topic T01

We have given permissions to user abc of connecting to queue manager QM01 and publish and subscriber to topic T01 using :

```
setmqaut -m QM01 -t queue -n T01-p abc -all +pub +sub
setmqaut -m QM01 -t qmgr -p abc -all +connect
```

and we have given only permission to xyz of connecting to queue manager QM01 and no permissions on Topic T01 using:

```
setmqaut -m QM01 -t queue -n T01 -p xyz -all
setmqaut -m QM01 -t qmgr -p xyz -all +connect
```

But still when an amqp client use amqp://localhost:5671 to connect to topic T01 ... a subscriber with subusr xyz created on topic T01

Ideally it should not be able to subscribe to topic T01 as it is having user xyz which have no permissions

Please help on this. How can we achieve this?

Comment: What is you AMQP channels' `USECLTID` parameter set to?  What about `TPROOT` and `MCAUSER`?

Comment: @JoshMc  ... what we tried above is working correctly ... I was trying on wrong topic and yes abc and xyz are our mcausers

Comment: You can delete your question if that is the case.

Comment: @JoshMc someone might get hints from our question if they come across it and trying same thing

Comment: @JoshMc one point we are still stuck on is ... how to make sure that client program is not able to modify subscriber attributes ... which in our case is EXPIRY of subscriber ... which it is setting to 0

Comment: I pinged a contract at IBM and provided a link to your question,  hopefully they can help

Comment: I suggest you self answer what the problem was.

Comment: @JoshMc sure .. I will answer my question